# Uninitialised variable warning for variable that is constructed

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

So I recently started a bit of a crusade to clear out some warnings that I get when I enable all the compiler warnings in GCC (-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic) but I'm getting a rather confusing warning about uninitialised values. Here is a (slightly simplified) view of what is happening:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

constexpr uint64_t MASK = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

double do_something(const double& rhs) {
   double tmp(rhs);
   reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(tmp) &= MASK;
   return tmp;
} 

int main() {
    std::cout << do_something(3.14159);
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
```

Basically I apply a bit mask `MASK` to the value of the double and then perform some other operation on the original data and the masked data. The other operation involves extra state that isn't relevant here, and the bit mask is stored elsewhere but is properly defined. Strangely, I got the following compiler warning

```
<source>: In function 'double do_something(const double&)':
<source>:8:32: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    8 |    reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(tmp) &= MASK;
      |                                ^~~
<source>:8:37: warning: 'tmp' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
    8 |    reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(tmp) &= MASK;
      |    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
<source>:7:11: note: 'tmp' declared here
    7 |    double tmp(rhs);
```

although the context of the warning points to the &= operation on the reinterpreted data. I presume this is because the compiler can't see through the reinterpret cast to see the valid data initialised on the line above held in the (reinterpreted) reference to uint64_t. Is this correct? And if not, can anyone enlighten me?

Disclaimer: I know that some of you will be put off by the reinterpret cast, but this is crucial to the way this particular piece of the code functions and (warnings aside) it is a "safe" operation in this context.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please post a [mcve].

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(tmp) &= MASK;` looks like UB. You're reading from and writing to a variable as if it were something that it is not. What compiler and options are you using? Perhaps the UB makes it do something that you didn't expect that leaves `tmp` uninitialized?

Comment: ... cont. To elaborate: Since the operation `reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(tmp) &= MASK;` has UB, why should the compiler even initialize `tmp`? It could just skip that.

Comment: `memcpy` is the way to go (or [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) since C++20). else you break strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Note that you need `-O2` or `-O3` to trigger the warnings. Not a good sign. I suggest that you add `-Werror` to your builds.

Comment: Thanks for adding the example. This code is from a mature library that has been exhaustively tested on all platforms and all major compilers (GCC, Clang, MSVC, Intel). Casting to an integral type of the same size as a primitive value should not be undefined behaviour, although operating on it as if it were an integer is certainly not a valid double operation but this is not the point.

Comment: @SamM _"...Casting to an integral type of the same size as a primitive value should not be undefined behaviour..."_ - it's defined by the C++ Standard to be Undefined Behaviour  Read the __Type aliasing__ section here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1):

Use `memcpy`. Do not type-punne pointers.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

constexpr uint64_t MASK = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

double do_something2(const double& rhs) {
   double tmp(rhs);
   uint64_t tmp64 = 0;
   static_assert(sizeof(uint64_t) >= sizeof(double));
   memcpy(&tmp64, &tmp, sizeof(double));
   tmp64 &= MASK;
   memcpy(&tmp, &tmp64, sizeof(double));
   return tmp;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << do_something2(3.14159);
}
```

You can also use `unsigned char` to inspect anything:

```
double do_something3(const double& rhs) {
    double tmp(rhs);
    unsigned char *tmpu = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&tmp);
    uint64_t mask = MASK; // TODO: handle endianess
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(double) / CHAR_BIT; ++i) {
        const unsigned char tmpmask = mask;
        mask >>= CHAR_BIT;
        *tmpu &= tmpmask;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: In the actual code, I generate the MASK and the integer type to match the size and endianness of double. I don't understand how casting into unsigned char pointers and then iterating over bytes is substantially different from simply using an inplace masking operation wholesale after casting to uint64_t.

Comment: @SamM because the cast to `uint64_t` invokes Undefined Behaviour. You can only cast to the original (or related) types and there is no relationship between `double` and `uint64_t`.

Comment: @SamM `I don't understand how casting into unsigned char pointers and then iterating over bytes` Please research strict aliasing rules, it's right in the warning message. I acces the object using unsigned char type - according to https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11 it's fine. `s substantially different from` The rule is clear, accessing a `double` using `uint64_t` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @TedLyngmo See my first comment, the actual integral type I use is chosen based on the size of double (and mask is generated with endianness in mind). The advantage of leveraging a little UB is that this can be done in place with no copies. (Although I imagine the optimiser would optimise away the memcopies and do this wholly within a register.

Comment: @KamilCuk This is not helpful, please try to actually add something to the discussion rather than telling me that I don't know something, I know this and that is why I ask.

Comment: @SamM I see your first comment. My previous comment was to KamilCuk. I removed that comment when he updated the answer. Regarding your first comment and later comments: Since this has UB explicitly written on it in the standard and you "_know this_", what are you really wondering about? That's the "_how_" part. Are you wondering _why_ they've chosen to make it UB?

Comment: Actually you answered my question in one of your comments above: "Since the operation reinterpret_cast<uint64_t&>(tmp) &= MASK; has UB, why should the compiler even initialize tmp? It could just skip that." This begs the question, is it possible that this operation does not perform the operation that I expect. (This is not what I have experienced thus far, but still.)

Comment: @SamM Great! Yes, It's possible. Anything goes when it comes to UB. The same piece of code could even behave differently if you put it in different parts of your program. It's really nasty.